# Regular expressions filter, with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Once again, I'm really bad with reg, I wonder if some1 could help me with this matching expression, with this posibles cases:

```
case 1 =  |ABC:(n)    
case 2 =  ABC:(n)
case 3 =  ABC:(n)|
```

where (n) is an integer.

so If I have an array which looks like this:

```
 ["ABC:2", "BVD:3", "BDS|ABC:3", "ABC:5|QWE:3"];
```

my filter after split, should return this:

```
 [2, 3, 5]
```

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andresmijares/5o8ryn4x/)

I will appreciate any help,

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: javascript, I just need a way to use the split() exploding

Comment: You are using split on an array?

Comment: yep, I use a $.grep first to get the "ABC:" matching array and them I need to the integer acoording to the cases

Comment: So why not use: `/\|?ABC:(\d+)\|?/`

Comment: that reg returns me the characters after the pipe, http://jsfiddle.net/andresmijares/5o8ryn4x/

Comment: That link gives error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: add jquery into the libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another line in your existing code that will split each of the parts by `|`, so that you get an array of the `ABC:(n)` parts:

```
var arr = oObj.split(",");
arr = $.map(arr, function(item) { return item.split("|"); });

// or, in native JS:
arr = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arr.map(function(item) { return item.split("|"); }));
```

No regex required at all!